# Split text into 3 parts

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a markdown file with a YAML header:

```
---
title: Welcome post
tags: [tech]
enabled: true
---

This is the post intro.

***

This is the post body.
```

I am reading the file using:

```
String text = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
```

How can I get, from text, the 3 parts of the file?

The YAML section between `---`:

```
title: Welcome post
tags: [tech]
enabled: true
```

The intro section, between `---` and `***`:

```
This is the post intro.
```

And the body section, after the `***`:

```
This is the post body.
```

**Note:** Sometimes there is no intro so only YAML and Body:

```
---
title: Welcome post
tags: [tech]
enabled: true
---

This is the post body.
```

**Update**

I was able to solve this by using:

```
String text = File.ReadAllText(file);

var result = text.Split(new String[] { "---", "***" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Not sure if it is the best way but it seems to work.

Comment: Have you tried using [a YAML parser](https://www.nuget.org/packages/YamlDotNet/)?

Comment: Don't read all the text, read it in using ReadAllLines or ReadLines.  Then look for your "---" and "***" line as you walk through the file

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yes, and I am using it to parse YAML text but I wasn't able to get the other two parts using YamlDotNet. There is why I am looking to split first in 3 parts and then do whatever I need after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a class to handle the parsing. Something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var yaml = new YamlParser("data.yaml");

        Debug.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, yaml.Head));
        // title: Welcome post
        // tags: [tech]
        // enabled: true
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, yaml.Intro));
        // This is the post intro.
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, yaml.Body));
        // This is the post body.
    }
}


public enum YamlSection
{
    Start,
    Header,
    Into,
    Body,
    Finished
}

public class YamlParser
{
    public YamlParser(string file)
        : this(System.IO.File.OpenText(file))
    {  }
    public YamlParser(StreamReader reader)
    {
        Head = new List<string>();
        Intro = new List<string>();
        Body = new List<string>();
        var section = YamlSection.Start;

        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (line.StartsWith("---") && section == YamlSection.Start)
            {
                section = YamlSection.Header;
            }
            else if (line.StartsWith("---") && section == YamlSection.Header)
            {
                section = YamlSection.Into;
            }
            else if (line.StartsWith("***"))
            {
                section =  YamlSection.Body;
            }
            else
            {
                switch (section)
                {
                    case YamlSection.Header:
                        Head.Add(line);
                        break;
                    case YamlSection.Into:
                        Intro.Add(line);
                        break;
                    case YamlSection.Body:
                        Body.Add(line);
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new NotSupportedException();
                }
            }
        }
        section = YamlSection.Finished;
    }

    public List<string> Head { get; }  
    public List<string> Intro { get; } 
    public List<string> Body { get; }  
}
```